# How to use asyncio to download files on s3 bucket

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto, boto3

I'm using the following code to download all my files in a s3 bucket:

```
def main(bucket_name, destination_dir):
    bucket = boto3.resource('s3').Bucket(bucket_name)
    for obj in bucket.objects.all():
        if obj.key.endswith('/'):
            continue
        destination = '%s/%s' % (bucket_name, obj.key)
        if not os.path.exists(destination):
            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(destination), exist_ok=True)
        bucket.download_file(obj.key, destination)
```

I would like to know how to make this asynchronous, if possible.

Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `generate_presigned_url` method of the s3 client to get the URL with AWS credentials (see [docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-presigned-urls.html)), and then send a request to download a file through the async HTTP client ([aiohttp](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html) for example)

aiohttp applies URL canonicalization which can cause issues if the Key includes spaces or non-ASCII characters. Using `URL(..., encoded=True)` will fix this issue.

```
import boto3
import asyncio
from aiohttp import client
from yarl import URL

bucket = 'some-bucket-name'

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
s3_objs = s3_client.list_objects(Bucket=bucket)['Contents']

async def download_s3_obj(key: str, aiohttp_session: client.ClientSession):
    request_url = s3_client.generate_presigned_url('get_object', {
        'Bucket': bucket,
        'Key': key
    })

    async with aiohttp_session.get(URL(request_url, encoded=True)) as response:
        file_path = 'some-local-folder-name/' + key.split('/')[-1]

        with open(file_path, 'wb') as file:
            file.write(await response.read())

async def get_tasks():
    session = client.ClientSession()

    return [download_s3_obj(f['Key'], session) for f in s3_objs], session

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
tasks, session = loop.run_until_complete(get_tasks())
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))

loop.run_until_complete(session.close())
```

Answer (score 3):

[Aiobotocore](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiobotocore) provides asyncio support for botocore library using aiohttp. If you are willing to modify your code to use [botocore](https://github.com/boto/botocore) instead, that would be a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box, boto3 doesn't support asyncio. There's a [tracking issue](https://github.com/boto/botocore/issues/458) opened on this that offers some workarounds; they may or may not work for your use case.