# Can I use the python s3fs library over aiobotocore?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, botocore, python-s3fs

[s3fs](https://pypi.org/project/s3fs/) is a convenient Python filesystem-like interface for S3, built on top of [botocore](https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html).  To access S3 using asyncio, [aiobotocore](https://aiobotocore.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is an [alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50394548/974555) to [botocore](https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html).  Is it possible to use s3fs with asyncio/[aiobotocore](https://aiobotocore.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) rather than vanilla [botocore](https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html)?

My use case is that I need to collect three items: one is coming from a tape archive, one from S3, and one is calculated with CPU.  They all take 10-30 minutes but concurrency should be possible here.